# MySQL Organisation Strategy for Multi-user with 100% customization

Tags: php, mysql, sql, architecture

My question today is how should I organize my MySQL Table to get a 100% customized menu for my different users...

Let me explain: I will have a large menu tree (like windows) that will display Categories & Items for the user. I want the user to be able to delete, add or Modify anything like: Category name, Delete category, Add item, Change item name and Delete Item.
BUT: I want to offer my different clients a starting "Base" menu with common Items and Categories when they register, but when a user modifies the category (ex: change name or delete it), I don't want his changes to interfere with the other user's Menu..

So, how should I organize my DB to handle this: at this moment, I have 2 Tables: **T_categories**(with parent info to structure for the tree menu)  & **T_items** (with category_id) but I realize that I don't really know how I will be handling my queries to enable "delete or rename" for Categories and Items... Should I make unlimited tables like this??

> T_user1_categories & T_user1_items
>
> T_user2_categories & T_user2_items

and so on, but if I have 1000 users it'll not be cool =/

At this time I can only(i think) create customized items with ex: privateview_id (user id)

**Also, if I build something that, when I rename a category, it create a new category with a privateview_ID, all the items that were already in it will lose their position**

I'm using PHP and MySQL

If you have an idea, i will be happy to hear it!!
Thank-you!

Raphael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally i've come to conclusion that the best way will be to create a table for every users... I've read that some people have MySql databases with over 1000+ tables without any problem and going the other way would be a lot of trouble. Also, I don't plan on having 1000+ users because that custom menu is part of a "paying" option. Thank-you for your answer jean

Answer (score 0):

A menu bar is a hierarchical thing. I suggest you "build" that things using a hierarchical meta data like XML.
You can store your users, categories and items in respective tables and also create a menus table to store the menus users created.
You ill still be able to do relations between users, menus, categories and items creating relational tables.
Also a user can just move a item from a category for another, not changing your usersXcategories or usersXitems relations but just changing the XML.

I cannot say more without knowing more details but your requirements.